# How to create trigger that works in cycle?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to count the number of "approved" items from one table and show this number in another. Like the progress bar. To do this I've made a trigger, but it doesn't work.

```
BEGIN
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(NEW.size,'|')
@len = sp_spaceused value
WHILE @len > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE size_control_men
        SET number_of_approved_items =  number_of_approved_items +1
        WHERE Size_MEN = NEW.size
        @len = @len - 1;
    END
END
```

First of all, I've got sizes (size) in one row in this format - `45|43|42`
so I have to go through all of them in a cycle, in `BEGIN
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(NEW.size,'|')
@len = sp_spaceused value` I do count the number of them, then in a cycle I'm incrementing the number of "approved" items.

But this trigger doesn't work at all :(

This trigger added to table dispatch:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|                     .........                                     |
|                     .........                                     |
|                     .........                                     |
| size       | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

size_control_men

```
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Size_MEN                 | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| number_of_approved_items | int(5)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The sample of dispatch table:[image]

And the counter of approved items: [image]

Comment: Relevant Table structure and sample data would be helpful!

Comment: 5 sec, I'll add them

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya done

Comment: There is no STRING_SPLIT function in MySQL!

Comment: that code isn't the complete trigger code.. Besides `STRING_SPLIT` function isn't shared also.

Comment: Also, share the relevant sample data for both the tables and expected output in the dispatch table

Comment: so, there's nothing like string_split function in mysql?

Comment: "so, there's nothing like string_split function in mysql? " indeed MySQL does not have a native string_split function.. besides is you use "delimiter" separated values in your data model you are using the relational database in totaly the wrong way..

Comment: @RaymondNijland sad, but true